# Flight simuation rotation leveling off

Tags: scripting, game-engine

I'm creating a flight simulator game with realistic acceleration, but a rotation of the ship doesn't level off after going a little while out, like normal flight games. I need to create some code that will slowly rotate the ship so it is horizontal to my ground. I was thinking of a way like creating a property, and every time I'm pressing a button to rotate my ship, it would create a positive or negative number in the property. Then, when I let go of the button, it would delay a short time, and then level off an amount based on the number in the property. I don't know much code, but I used some code to create realistic acceleration for the ship, so I have some knowledge. If there is a better way of doing this, please let me know. I don't know if you can do this with logic bricks, but if you've got a solution, I'll be happy with it. [image]

Comment: Michael, welcome to the site. If your question is how to do this in the Blender game engine, it would be helpful to edit this into your question.

Comment: @brasshat hey, i dont really know how to use this website, and i cilcked on your name and it brought me to all the questions you answered, but none of them had to do anything with my problem really. I'm not new to blender, i can do relatively complex things, i just don't know very much about python scripiting, and needed a solution. please, if you could give me step by step instructions on scripting (almost like i'm 5(i'm 16 though)) that would be greatly apreiciated.

Comment: Michael, Python coding is not yet part of my skillset, so regrettably, I cannot give you step by step instructions on how to use Python scripting to do what you want. Truth to tell, I'm not all that familiar with the particulars of the various game engines in which you might be intending your game, but it is my impression that the way to achieve in game the effect that you want, likely is different in different game engines, so it would be useful to know which game engine you have in mine.

Comment: @brasshat alright. Am i missing something? i thought there was only one game engine in blender. BGE. Correct? i want to do a 3rd person game (i dont know if i mentioned that) and i dont necessarily need to use scripting, i am fine with the simple logic blocks for BGE.

Comment: Michael, yes there is only one game engine *in* Blender, but so many people use Blender to create games, or content for games in other game engines, too, like Unity, Unreal enigne, and others, that I didn't choose to assume you were using BGE. I can;t help much with BGE, because I create content for a game engine I didn't name above.